# Receiving SMS messages in Android 1.6

Tags: android, sms, android-1.6-donut

I have a code sample (from Reto Meier's book) on receiving SMS messages in an android application using a broadcast receiver.

I am looking to be able to receive a SMS message in my application however the code I already have a sample of seems to be depreciated from what I can tell...

Does anyone have a more up to date (android 1.5 or 1.6) example of how to receive SMS messages in an android application?

Thanks.
Tom.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you show us what you have or tell us what you think might be wrong with it?

The general steps for receiving an SMS are pretty easy. Basically you build a [BroadcastReceiver](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) with the intent filter of `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`. There are several tutorials on this topic out there. A quick Google search turned up [this one](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/) and [this one](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android).