# Sending and Receiving SMS and MMS in Android (pre Kit Kat Android 4.4)

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, mms

I have figured out how to send and receive SMS messages.  To send SMS messages I had to call the `sendTextMessage()` and `sendMultipartTextMessage()` methods of the `SmsManager` class.  To receive SMS messages, I had to register a receiver in the `AndroidMainfest.xml` file.  Then I had to override the `onReceive()` method of the `BroadcastReceiver`.  I have included examples below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    private static String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    private static int MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 160;

    // ---sends an SMS message to another device---
    public static void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {

        PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        int length = message.length();          
        if(length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
            ArrayList<String> messagelist = smsManager.divideMessage(message);          
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messagelist, null, null);
        }
        else
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, piSent, piDelivered);
        }
    }

    //More methods of MainActivity ...
}
```

**SMSReceiver.java**

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String DEBUG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
    private static final String ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private Context mContext;
    private Intent mIntent;

    // Retrieve SMS
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mIntent = intent;

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED)){

            String address, str = "";
            int contactId = -1;

            SmsMessage[] msgs = getMessagesFromIntent(mIntent);
            if (msgs != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    address = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    contactId = ContactsUtils.getContactId(mContext, address, "address");
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                }
            }   

            if(contactId != -1){
                showNotification(contactId, str);
            }

            // ---send a broadcast intent to update the SMS received in the
            // activity---
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }

    }

    public static SmsMessage[] getMessagesFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        Object[] messages = (Object[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("pdus");
        byte[][] pduObjs = new byte[messages.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            pduObjs[i] = (byte[]) messages[i];
        }
        byte[][] pdus = new byte[pduObjs.length][];
        int pduCount = pdus.length;
        SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pduCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < pduCount; i++) {
            pdus[i] = pduObjs[i];
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i]);
        }
        return msgs;
    }

    /**
    * The notification is the icon and associated expanded entry in the status
    * bar.
    */
    protected void showNotification(int contactId, String message) {
        //Display notification...
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            //Main activity...
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            //Activity 2 ...
        </activity>
        //More acitivies ...

        // SMS Receiver
        <receiver android:name="com.myexample.receivers.SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

However, I was wondering if you could send and receive MMS messages in a similar fashion.  After doing some research, many examples provided on blogs simply pass an `Intent` to the native Messaging application.  I am trying to send an MMS without leaving my application.  There doesn't seem to be a standard way of sending and receiving MMS.  Has anyone gotten this to work?

Also, I am aware that the SMS/MMS ContentProvider is not a part of the official Android SDK, but I was thinking someone may have been able to implement this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

## Update

I have added a `BroadcastReceiver` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to receive MMS messages

```
<receiver android:name="com.sendit.receivers.MMSReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />

        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the MMSReceiver class, the `onReceive()` method is only able to grab the phoneNumber that the message was sent from.  How do you grab other important things from an MMS such as the file path to the media attachment (image/audio/video), or the text in the MMS?

**MMSReceiver.java**

```
public class MMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String DEBUG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
    private static final String ACTION_MMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED";
    private static final String MMS_DATA_TYPE = "application/vnd.wap.mms-message";

     // Retrieve MMS
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if(action.equals(ACTION_MMS_RECEIVED) && type.equals(MMS_DATA_TYPE)){

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "bundle " + bundle);
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";
            int contactId = -1;
            String address;

            if (bundle != null) {

                byte[] buffer = bundle.getByteArray("data");
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "buffer " + buffer);
                String incomingNumber = new String(buffer);
                int indx = incomingNumber.indexOf("/TYPE");
                if(indx>0 && (indx-15)>0){
                    int newIndx = indx - 15;
                    incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(newIndx, indx);
                    indx = incomingNumber.indexOf("+");
                    if(indx>0){
                        incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(indx);
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile Number: " + incomingNumber);
                    }
                }

                int transactionId = bundle.getInt("transactionId");
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "transactionId " + transactionId);

                int pduType = bundle.getInt("pduType");
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "pduType " + pduType);

                byte[] buffer2 = bundle.getByteArray("header");      
                String header = new String(buffer2);
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "header " + header);

                if(contactId != -1){
                    showNotification(contactId, str);
                }

                // ---send a broadcast intent to update the MMS received in the
                // activity---
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                broadcastIntent.setAction("MMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("mms", str);
                context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

            }
        }

    }

    /**
    * The notification is the icon and associated expanded entry in the status
    * bar.
    */
    protected void showNotification(int contactId, String message) {
        //Display notification...
    }
}
```

According to the [Documentation of android.provider.Telephony](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/provider/Telephony.java?av=f):

> Broadcast Action: A new text based SMS message has been received by the device. The intent will have the following extra values:
>
> `pdus` - An `Object[]` of `byte[]`s containing the PDUs that make up the message.
>
> The extra values can be extracted using `getMessagesFromIntent(android.content.Intent)`
>   If a BroadcastReceiver encounters an error while processing this intent it should set the result code appropriately.
>
> ```
>  @SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
>  public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Broadcast Action: A new data based SMS message has been received by the device. The intent will have the following extra values:
>
> `pdus` - An `Object[]` of `byte[]`s containing the PDUs that make up the message.
>
> The extra values can be extracted using getMessagesFromIntent(android.content.Intent).
>   If a BroadcastReceiver encounters an error while processing this intent it should set the result code appropriately.
>
> ```
> @SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
> public static final String DATA_SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED";
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Broadcast Action: A new WAP PUSH message has been received by the device. The intent will have the following extra values:
>
> `transactionId (Integer)` - The WAP transaction ID
>
> `pduType (Integer)` - The WAP PDU type`
>
> `header (byte[])` - The header of the message
>
> `data (byte[])` - The data payload of the message
>
> `contentTypeParameters (HashMap<String,String>)` - Any parameters associated with the content type (decoded from the WSP Content-Type header)
>
> If a BroadcastReceiver encounters an error while processing this intent it should set the result code appropriately.
>   The contentTypeParameters extra value is map of content parameters keyed by their names.
>   If any unassigned well-known parameters are encountered, the key of the map will be 'unassigned/0x...', where '...' is the hex value of the unassigned parameter. If a parameter has No-Value the value in the map will be null.
>
> ```
> @SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
> public static final String WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED";
> ```

## Update #2

I have figured out how to pass extras in a `PendingIntent` to be received by a `BroadcastReceiver`:
[Android PendingIntent extras, not received by BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571564/android-pendingintent-extras-not-received-by-broadcastreceiver)

However, the extra gets passed to the *SendBroadcastReceiver* not the *SMSReceiver*.  How can I pass an extra to the *SMSReceiver*?

## Update #3

**Receiving MMS**

So after doing more research I saw some suggestions of registering a `ContentObserver`.  That way you can detect when there are any changes to the `content://mms-sms/conversations` Content Provider, consequently allowing you to detect incoming MMS.  Here is the closest example to get this to work that I have found: [Receiving MMS](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/where-can-i-find-information-about-sending-receiving-mms-t51284.html)

However, there is a variable `mainActivity` of type `ServiceController`.  Where is the `ServiceController` class implemented?  Are there any other implementations of a registered `ContentObserver`?

**Sending MMS**

As for sending MMS, I have come across this example: [Send MMS](http://www.ziddu.com/download/14286605/SendMMS3.zip.html)

The problem is that I tried running this code on my Nexus 4, which is on Android v4.2.2, and I am receiving this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings: Neither user 10099 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS.
```

The error gets thrown after querying the `Carriers` ContentProvider in the `getMMSApns()` method of the `APNHelper` class.

```
final Cursor apnCursor = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), null, null, null, null);
```

Apparently you can't [read APNs in Android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453640/read-apns-in-android-4-2)

What is the alternative for all those applications which use mobile data to perform operations (like sending MMS) and don't know the default APN setting present in the device?

## Update #4

**Sending MMS**

I have tried following this example: [Send MMS](http://www.ziddu.com/download/14286605/SendMMS3.zip.html)

As @Sam suggested in his answer:

`You have to add jsoup to the build path, the jar to the build path and import com.droidprism.*; To do that in android, add the jars to the libs directory first, then configure the project build path to use the jars already in the libs directory, then on the build path config click order and export and check the boxes of the jars and move jsoup and droidprism jar to the top of the build order.`

So now I no longer get the SecurityException errors.  I am testing now on a Nexus 5 on Android KitKat.  After running the sample code it gives me a 200 response code after the call to

```
MMResponse mmResponse = sender.send(out, isProxySet, MMSProxy, MMSPort);
```

However, I checked with the person I tried sending the MMS to. And they said they never received the MMS.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this tutorial before? http://maximbogatov.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/mms-in-android/

Comment: Yes I have. I tried piecing Maxim's answer together but am not able to get it to work. There are many classes in there that import android.provider.telephony which seems to be deprecated.

Comment: And presumably, after reading @Sahil's answer, you've also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016

Comment: I'm not sure how to piece that answer together, although it looks very similar to @Sahil's answer.

Comment: Hi @toobsco42 are you able to find the solution for all those query you mention above.. ?

Comment: Hey @kamal_tech_view, I still am looking for an answer to this problem.  I have posted several updates of progress I have made many attempts at certain code examples but nothing has been successful.  Do  you have any ideas?  I will accept an answer if in fact it addresses sending and receiving MMS.

Comment: regarding reading the incoming mms I find the better approach is to read the mms content with url but I am unable to download the mms content you can find this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060173/android-mms-download-mms-content-through-mms-url#comment23231605_16060173

Comment: I've tried the ContentObserver method, and the BroadcastReceiver method for receiving MMS messages and with either approach the problem is that my app receives the MMS-received notification *way* before the built-in text app shows a message. So my app sounds the alarm, then the user goes to look in their texting app, and the image of the new message isn't showing yet. About 3 minutes later the texting app will have the image visible. How to prevent my app from sounding the alarm too soon ?

Comment: Looks like there may be some changes ahead of us : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Answer (score 15):

I had the exact same problem you describe above (Galaxy Nexus on t-mobile USA) it is because mobile data is turned off.

In Jelly Bean it is:
Settings > Data Usage > mobile data

Note that I have to have mobile data turned on PRIOR to sending an MMS OR receiving one. If I receive an MMS with mobile data turned off, I will get the notification of a new message and I will receive the message with a download button. But if I do not have mobile data on prior, the incoming MMS attachment will not be received. Even if I turn it on after the message was received.

For some reason when your phone provider enables you with the ability to send and receive MMS you must have the Mobile Data enabled, even if you are using Wifi, if the Mobile Data is enabled you will be able to receive and send MMS, even if Wifi is showing as your internet on your device.

It is a real pain, as if you do not have it on, the message can hang a lot, even when turning on Mobile Data, and might require a reboot of the device.

Comment: Also you must know that sending a SMS and MMS are 2 entirely different things in background. 
MMS is more of an internet based network service as it requires sending additional items(Media) with text.
The given code works fine on a few devices that i've tested on.

ps : you can ignore the NOKIA part.

Comment: When i run this example, in LogCat it prints:

02-24 13:32:40.872: V/SendMMSActivity(5686):    TYPE_MOBILE_MMS not connected, bail
02-24 13:32:40.882: V/SendMMSActivity(5686):    type is not TYPE_MOBILE_MMS, bail

It also says:

java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings: Neither user 10099 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS.

It looks like it can't execute this query:
final Cursor apnCursor = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), null, null, null, null);

Im testing on a Nexus 4.

Comment: Also this is the same example that @Sahil provided.

Answer (score 7):

There is not official api support which means that it is not documented for the public and the libraries may change at any time. I realize you don't want to leave the application but here's how you do it with an intent for anyone else wondering.

```
public void sendData(int num){
    String fileString = "..."; //put the location of the file here
    Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "text");
    mmsIntent.putExtra("address", num);
    mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(fileString)));
    mmsIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mmsIntent, "Send"));

}
```

I haven't completely figured out how to do things like track the delivery of the message but this should get it sent.

You can be alerted to the receipt of mms the same way as sms. The intent filter on the receiver should look like this.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Doesn't this just launch the native Messaging app?

Comment: yeah sorry about that. i just realized that you already knew how to do that. i did add how to receive mms though.

Comment: Thanks, I have recently been implementing part of the MMS `BroadcastReceiver`, and have used the `Intent Filter` that you have posted.  I will update this question soon.

Answer (score 4):

To send an mms for Android 4.0 api 14 or higher without permission to write apn settings, you can use [this library](http://droidprism.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-library-for-retrieving-sms-email.html): 
Retrieve mnc and mcc codes from android, then call

```
Carrier c = Carrier.getCarrier(mcc, mnc);
if (c != null) {
    APN a = c.getAPN();
    if (a != null) {
        String mmsc = a.mmsc;
        String mmsproxy = a.proxy; //"" if none
        int mmsport = a.port; //0 if none
    }
}
```

To use this, add [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download) and droid prism jar to the build path, and import com.droidprism.*;

Comment: Hey @Sam, I added the .jar file to my project but am getting this error at the line that instantiates the Carrier object :

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.droidprism.Carrier`  is that happening to you?

Comment: no. You have to add jsoup to the build path, the jar to the build path and import com.droidprism.*; I'll edit the answer. To do that in android, add the jars to the libs directory first, then configure the project build path to use the jars already in the libs directory, then on the build path config click order and export and check the boxes of the jars and move jsoup and droidprism jar to the top of the build order.

Comment: Adding the Jsoup .jar resolved the NoClassDefFoundError.  I can now get the APN settings.  The next step is to figure out how to send MMS.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there is any sdk support for sending mms in android. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7311382/1626878) Atleast I havent found yet. But a guy claimed to have it. Have a look at this post.

[Send MMS from My application in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073821/1626878)

Comment: I looked at the comments of the androidbridge.blogspot.com post of the Nokia implementation, and it looks like many people are having issues getting this to work on their devices.

Comment: @toobsco42 So, there might be no support for it yet.

Answer (score -2):

I dont understand the frustrations.  Why not just make a broadcastreceiver that filters for this intent:

```
android.provider.Telephony.MMS_RECEIVED
```

I checked a little further and you might need system level access to get this (rooted phone).

Comment: Hey @j2emanue, The problem is after you receive this intent, how do you actually get the content of the MMS?  If an MMS contains and image and text, how do you extract these components.

Comment: but i notice theres a byte array extra you can get if you do it the  way .i mentioned ....
    byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra("data");
im not sure how to parse it though sorry.

Comment: i am able to parse it.  but all i can get is the subject, who the mms came from, and the contentlocation where the content of the mms is stored.  however this url is not accessible.

Answer (score -3):

> SmsListenerClass

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

static final String ACTION =
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("RECEIVED", ":-:-" + "SMS_ARRIVED");

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {

        Log.e("RECEIVED", ":-" + "SMS_ARRIVED");

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            SmsMessage message = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    String format = bundle.getString("format");
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
                } else {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }

                message = messages[i];
                buf.append("Received SMS from  ");
                buf.append(message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                buf.append(" - ");
                buf.append(message.getDisplayMessageBody());
            }

            MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();
            inst.updateList(message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress(),message.getDisplayMessageBody());

        }

        Log.e("RECEIVED:", ":" + buf.toString());

        Toast.makeText(context, "RECEIVED SMS FROM :" + buf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

> Activity

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

public static MainActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

public void updateList(final String msg_from, String msg_body) {

    tvMessage.setText(msg_from + " :- " + msg_body);

    sendSMSMessage(msg_from, msg_body);

}

protected void sendSMSMessage(String phoneNo, String message) {

    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```