# Are Android folders Outbox, Inbox, Sent Box actual folders/categories in the ANdroid system?

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to get into android programming..but needed to know a few things to clear the road.. one of w/c is the message handling of android..

So when using an android phone you can see INBOX , OUTBOX, SEnt, Draft, etc

are these real folders, or different tables in the android system? or same table w/ different category ID or something like that?

What I wanted to do is manage my SMS messages through my App (preferably Phonegap package). I was assuming this is a simple sql query to android's sql lite?

More importantly I wanted to be able to simply send sms by "putting" the said message in the outbox.

I was assuming that, android constantly scans the "outbox" and sends any message put there and moves said message to "sentbox" etc. So i'd simply have my app just put messages in said folder or table and Android will take care of the rest.

Is this how android works? or is it at least possible to do things this way?

I know I read that I could create my own SMS app and have the different types of messages stored in the way I like it , but I really wanted to simplify things and use the existing / built in android way of doing things. This way, even if my app has crashed or is off, all messages received or sent manually by the user, go into their default inbox, outbox, sentbox folders, and the next time I fire up my app , everything is in the sample place  (not having to have my own inbox/outbox tables etc)

regards to all

Comment: You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-and-mms-in-android-pre-kit-kat-android-4-4 which covers many of these topics in great detail