# Using method defined in android SDK api

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use the method `getMessagesFromIntent(Intent intent)` defined in Android SDK API. You can see its definition from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#getMessagesFromIntent(android.content.Intent)).

However, even after I import `android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents` which contains the method, I get the method is not defined. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-and-mms-in-android-pre-kit-kat-android-4-4) defines the method from scratch but I am confused why I can't just use the one defined inside the above library. Am I understanding something wrong? Could anyone explain why I cannot use `getMessagesFromIntent(Intent intent)`?

Comment: Is your build SDK android-19?

Comment: what is your build SDK and how do you call that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you linked, it mentions the following on the right of the title describing the method:

```
Added in API level 19
```

So to use this method, you must set your build target to be 19 or higher. Even then, only devices that support API 19 or higher will be able to make use of it.