# How to send MMS with command, like SMS in Android

Tags: android, adb, mms

I know there is adb command to send SMS:
adb shell am start -a  "android.intent.action.SEND"  -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es mms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
What I need is to send MMS(audio file) from device to another.
Can anyone help on this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: See, my friend ->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-and-mms-in-android-pre-kit-kat-android-4-4

Comment: I saw the post, it is starting activity in Activity extended class. It is not suitable to me, I don't want to create activity, need to start activity in command. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: how are you connecting to the remote device? Bluetooth? TCP/IP and sockets?  GCM?   The answer to that will determine how you send data

Comment: I am doing Android testing, it is black-box testing, I need to send MMS through ADB command with device connected to computer.

Comment: I want to do the same thing, to send MMS using adb shell. Is this possible?