# How to delete particular inbox message in Android version 5.0 lollipop or in Kitkat?

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am making to delete particular sms of phone number task. when I am testing in motog or Android version 5.0's mobile. I can't delete particular number's sms. My code snippet is below.

```
public void deleteSMS(Context context,String number) {
    try {
        Log.d("","Deleting SMS from inbox");
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address",
                        "person", "date", "body" }, "address = '"+number+"'", null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS with id: " + threadId +" Number:- " +address,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("", "SMS with id: " + threadId +" Number:- " +address);
                if ( address.equals(number)) {
                    Log.d("", "Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not delete SMS from inbox ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("", "Could not delete SMS from inbox: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your app the default SMS app? If not, it doesn't have standard write access to the Provider.

Comment: I want to delete sms from phone inbox by programmatically as per above code.it works for below 4.4 android version.but it is not working in above 4.4 version.

Comment: Check out the following blog page. It should explain why it doesn't work in those versions. [Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending and Receiving SMS and MMS in Android (pre Kit Kat Android 4.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-and-mms-in-android-pre-kit-kat-android-4-4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After 4.4 you are not allowed to delete any sms messages from inbox unless your app is the "default sms app"

> Beginning with Android 4.4, the system settings allow users to select a "default SMS app." Once selected, only the default SMS app is able to write to the SMS Provider and only the default SMS app receives the SMS_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an SMS or the WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an MMS. The default SMS app is responsible for writing details to the SMS Provider when it receives or sends a new message.
>
> Other apps that are not selected as the default SMS app **can only read
>   the SMS Provider**...

[You can see More info here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)
just mentioned the important part below:

> if your app is designed to behave as the default SMS app, then while your app is not selected as the default, it's important that you understand the limitations placed upon your app and disable features as appropriate. Although the system writes sent SMS messages to the SMS Provider while your app is not the default SMS app, it does not write sent MMS messages and your app is not able to write to the SMS Provider for other operations, such as to mark messages as draft, mark them as read, delete them, etc.