# How to delete an SMS long click?

Tags: java, android

I have a code to delete an SMS:

```
public void deleteSMS(Context context, String message, String number) {
    try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
                new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address",
                        "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);

                if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("deletesms", e.toString());
    }
}
```

And I have a code to call longclick:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Deleted SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

Q: how do I delete inbox SMS by long click?
I second day looking answer on my question, but not found. I am disappointed.

P.S. I have android 4.2.2.

P.S.S. sorry for the question. I was exhausted.

Comment: What is the error/output you are getting?

Comment: is your app  "default sms app"? if not you can't delete sms. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33579889/2101822

Comment: What happening after removing `if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number))` condition ?

Comment: Is the problem the long click, or is it the delete of the SMS? You should be able to decide this yourself. Then edit your question and the title.