# Deleting SMS from custom Android library on kitkat or above

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm building an app to remove SMS in Android.
From Android kitkat or above, I understand I need to make my app as default SMS app from several sources like

[How to delete particular inbox message in android version 5.0 lolipop or in Kitkat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579293/how-to-delete-particular-inbox-message-in-android-version-5-0-lolipop-or-in-kitk/33579889#33579889)

I also tried the solution from http://pulse7.net/android/android-delete-sms-message-from-inbox-in-android/ and it worked perfect so I could remove messages one by one.

However, I'm trying to embed this solution in custom library and the following code in custom confirmation dialog does not work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

To make it work in library, I passed the `context` variable to the library and updated the code as follows.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone help me?